# MongoDB Compass connectivity issue with Ec2 Instance to access amazon documentDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have been trying to access my database that i created on Amazon DocumentDB via MongoDB Compass using Ec2 Instance but following is the error I keep on getting. There are no issues with the security groups, since I have made sure to give appropriate in bound request rights.

I am able to connect to the DocumentDB cluster via mongo shell after I SSH into the ec2-instance, but I cannot connect it via MongoDB Compass because it throws me the same error that has been attached in the image below

Please help!

[image: Please see error in the image attached here!]

Comment: Hello Naveel, what version of MongoDB Compass are you using? The error EADDRINUSE means you have an existing SSH tunnel on your client machine. Have you setup a SSH tunnel via the terminal?

Comment: Hi john. 

I am using 1.21.2 on mac, and i have not setup an ssh tunnel via terminal since if i do that it hangs me on my terminal after executing the command for ever.

Comment: Nabeel - the hang means the tunnel was successfully setup. If you are having issues with Compass, I would also recommend you take a look at another popular GUI management tool Robo 3T: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-3-getting-started-with-amazon-documentdb-using-robo-3t/

Answer (score 0):

Just use your pem file and set localhost port example here port 8000. Once run this below command then just open mongo compass and host: localhost:8000 then it will connect.

***ssh -i my-aws-key.pem -N -f -L 8000:localhost:27017 ec2-user@serverIp***

[image]